# how to navigate to new page when click on path svg in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, path

I have the following svg image (each circle has a different path)
and my app contains 5 classes,
I want to include it in my app so that when the user clicks on any circle, it goes to another page (navigate to new class) and each circle has a different class than the other
How can this be done in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: In SVG the [<a> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) creates a hyperlink to other web pages. Wrap the path in a <a> element.

Comment: thank you can you provide me some code ?

Comment: Please read the MDN article linked in my previous comment

Comment: I do , my problem is how to replace the link by the name of class want to navigate to it ?

Comment: In this case push the edit button, rephrase your question and add the code you have. In the original question there is no mention of any class whatsoever

Comment: @devlop Would you please add the SVG source to the question?

Comment: @lepsch did you means from my assets folder

Comment: Yes, that would help

Answer (score 0):

This might be a workaround if there is another way but my first thought is to put your SVG image into a stack widget and place Positioned gesturedetectors over each circle area. Then point each Gesturedetector to each class you have.

There might be more elegant ways to go about it but this might get you going till you have a better solution

Comment: thank you, i think the best way is used canvas paint, but no way convert svg image to custom paint